# Access 2010 - Determine existence of record in one of three remote mdb files for subsequent select

Tags: vba, ms-access

There are three mdb files in folders on a network drive that may hold the required record(s). How do I determine which db holds the record(s), ideally without data transfer/linking/etc.? Then a single SQL or DAO select can get the data from the correct db. Note: I'm trying to use Access as a front end to SQL using existing Access data spread all around the network drives.

My current solution of configuring 3 DAO objects and checking for no results, in succession until found, seems to load the remote tables to the local recordset and takes too long.

Is there a way to use IF EXISTS in this scenario?

This code throws "Invalid SQL statement; expected DELETE,INSERT,PROCEDURE,SELECT,OR UPDATE" error but is generally what I'd like to do :

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strSku As String
Dim intDbToSearch As Integer
strSku = DLookup("SKUNo", "tblCurrentItem")   'Note: this returns valid SKU#
strSQL = "IF EXISTS(SELECT xxTable.SKUNo "
strSQL = strSQL & "FROM [S:\Our Inventory\Cust Sleeves.mdb].[xxTable] "
strSQL = strSQL & "Where xxTable.SKUNo = " & "'" & strSku & "') Then intDbToSearch = 1"  

DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

This is one of three IF Exists that would run if SKUNo not found in db 1 or 2.

Ultimately intDbToSearch should point to db 1,2,or 3 if SKUNo found or 0 if not.

Thanks

In the end, I pushed usage rules for the 3 databases upstream and can now predetermine which database to search. Thanks again for your input.

Comment: I don't think Access SQL recognizes IF EXISTS. Regardless, RunSQL is for action sql like DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE, CREATE TABLE. Options: 1. Declare and open a recordset object and check its recordcount property 2. set table links and use DLookup() on the link.

Comment: @June7 - I was hoping I was misusing IF EXISTS being a rookie. I am using your option 1 now or at least have the first of the 3 built and tested.  Thank you.

Comment: @June7 - if you write option 1 up I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: That's okay. If you developed working code and want to show answer for other readers, go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Will the sought for SKU always occur in only 1 of the tables?

If you don't want to set table links or use VBA recordsets, only other approach I can see is a query object with a dynamic parameter that references a form control for the SKU input. No idea if this will be faster and will need a query for each remote table.
`SELECT SKUNo FROM xxTable IN "S:\Our Inventory\Cust Sleeves.mdb" WHERE SKUNo = Forms!formname!cbxSKU`

Then just do DCount on the query.

```
Dim intDbToSearch As Integer
If DCount("*", "xxQuery") > 0 Then
    intDbToSearch = 1
End If
```

Could UNION the SELECT statements so would have only 1 query object to work with.

```
SELECT "x1" AS Source, SKUNo FROM xxTable IN "S:\Our Inventory 1\Cust Sleeves.mdb" WHERE SKUNo = Forms!formname!cbxSKU
UNION SELECT "x2", SKUNo FROM xxTable IN "S:\Our Inventory 2\Cust Sleeves.mdb" WHERE SKUNo = Forms!formname!cbxSKU
UNION SELECT "x3", SKUNo FROM xxTable IN "S:\Our Inventory 3\Cust Sleeves.mdb" WHERE SKUNo = Forms!formname!cbxSKU;
```

Comment: I'll try this approach and let you know. I have a machine down so I don't know if I'll get to it today. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @ June 7 - I missed the question yesterday, answer is yes, in a perfect world. In reality, those tables are manually maintained so ...

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple Function to check if exists by passing the table name and value?

Something like this:

```
Public Function ExistInTable(Byval TableName As String, ByVal Value As String) As Boolean
    ExistInTable = (DCount("*", TableName, "[SKUNo]='" & Value & "'" > 0)
End Function
```

To call it:

```
Sub Test()
    If ExistInTable("T1", "Whatever") Then 'Exists in T1
    If ExistInTable("T2", "Whatever") Then 'Exists in T2
    '....
End Sub
```

Comment: Would have to set links to the remote tables to use domain aggregate function.

Comment: @Kostas K - I'll look at this but I think June7 is correct. It seems difficult to get to remote data without links in Access. Thank you.